# How to make multi record join show up in main section

Tags: xslt

This is the file coming out:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
  <soapenv:Body>
    <ns1:getDocumentByKeyResponse xmlns:ns1="http://www.taleo.com/ws/integration/toolkit/2005/07" soapenv:encodingStyle="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/">
      <Document xmlns="http://www.taleo.com/ws/integration/toolkit/2005/07">
        <Attributes>
          <Attribute name="count">1</Attribute>
          <Attribute name="duration">0:00:00.102</Attribute>
          <Attribute name="entity">Requisition</Attribute>
          <Attribute name="mode">T-XML</Attribute>
          <Attribute name="version">http://www.taleo.com/ws/tee800/2009/01</Attribute>
        </Attributes>
        <Content>
          <ExportTXML xmlns:e="http://www.taleo.com/ws/tee800/2009/01" xmlns="http://www.taleo.com/ws/integration/toolkit/2005/07">
            <e:Requisition>
              <e:ContestNumber>15000005</e:ContestNumber>
              <e:JobInformation>
                <e:JobInformation>
                  <e:OtherLocations>
                    <e:Location>
                      <e:ZipCode>77002</e:ZipCode>
                    </e:Location>
                    <e:Location>
                      <e:ZipCode>77050</e:ZipCode>
                    </e:Location>
                  </e:OtherLocations>
                  <e:PrimaryLocation>
                    <e:Location>
                      <e:ZipCode>77003</e:ZipCode>
                    </e:Location>
                  </e:PrimaryLocation>
                </e:JobInformation>
              </e:JobInformation>
            </e:Requisition>
          </ExportTXML>
        </Content>
      </Document>
    </ns1:getDocumentByKeyResponse>
  </soapenv:Body>
</soapenv:Envelope>
```

I need it to look like so:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<source>
  <job>
    <job_id>
      <![CDATA[15000005]]>
    </job_id>
    <location_zipcode>
      <![CDATA[77002]]>
      <![CDATA[77050]]>    
      <![CDATA[77003]]>
    </location_zipcode>
  </job>
</source>
```

My current xsl looks like so:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="2.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" xmlns:e="http://www.taleo.com/ws/tee800/2009/01" xmlns:fct="http://www.taleo.com/xsl_functions" exclude-result-prefixes="e fct">
  <xsl:output method="xml" encoding="UTF-8" omit-xml-declaration="no" cdata-section-elements="job_id location_zipcode other_location_zipcode"/>
  <xsl:param name="OUTBOUND_FOLDER"/>
  <xsl:template match="/">
    <source>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="//e:Requisition"/>
    </source>
  </xsl:template>
  <xsl:template match="e:Requisition">
    <xsl:variable name="location_zipcode" select="e:JobInformation/e:JobInformation/e:PrimaryLocation/e:Location/e:NetworkLocation/e:NetworkLocation/e:ZipCode"/>
    <xsl:variable name="other_location_zipcode" select="e:JobInformation/e:JobInformation/e:OtherLocation/e:Location/e:NetworkLocation/e:NetworkLocation/e:ZipCode"/>
    <xsl:variable name="job_id" select="e:ContestNumber"/>
    <job>
      <job_id>
        <xsl:value-of select="$job_id"/>
      </job_id>
      <location_zipcode>
        <xsl:value-of select="$location_zipcode"/>
        <xsl:value-of select="$other_location_zipcode"/>
      </location_zipcode>
      </job>
      </xsl:template>
      </xsl:stylesheet>
```

This xslt makes it fail when it comes across more than 1 other location record.  I need it to keep pulling however many there are.  Any ideas would be most appreciated!
Thanks!
Greg

Comment: Your question is missing your input XML, please add it.

Comment: What is coming out is the first section of my post, is it not showing?

Comment: Then perhaps I misunderstood; I thought "what's coming out" is your current output, and the next snippet the expected output. So, is the first XML document the input?

Comment: You won't be able to put each separate zipcode in its own CDATA section using `cdata-section-elements`, the only way to do that would be to hack it with `disable-output-escaping`.  Not that there's any point putting a zip code in CDATA anyway as it should just be digits, you might as well just leave it as normal text.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following stylesheet:

**XSLT 1.0 or 2.0**

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="2.0" 
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" 
xmlns:e="http://www.taleo.com/ws/tee800/2009/01" 
exclude-result-prefixes="e">
<xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" indent="yes"/>

<xsl:template match="/">
    <source>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="//e:Requisition"/>
    </source>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="e:Requisition">
    <job>
        <job_id>
            <xsl:value-of select="e:ContestNumber"/>
        </job_id>
        <location_zipcode>
            <xsl:for-each select="..//e:Location">
                <xsl:text disable-output-escaping="yes">&lt;![CDATA[</xsl:text>
                <xsl:value-of select="e:ZipCode"/>
                <xsl:text disable-output-escaping="yes">]]&gt;</xsl:text>
                <xsl:text>&#10;</xsl:text>
            </xsl:for-each>
        </location_zipcode>
    </job>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

when applied to your example input (after cleaning up the redundant hyphens!) will return:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<source>
   <job>
      <job_id>15000005</job_id>
      <location_zipcode><![CDATA[77002]]>
<![CDATA[77050]]>
<![CDATA[77003]]>
</location_zipcode>
   </job>
</source>
```

A slightly more efficient version would replace the `//` shortcuts with full, explicit paths.

I was just about to add a note regarding the CDATA requirement, but Ian Roberts said it much better that I was going to: [How to make multi record join show up in main section](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28219751/how-to-make-multi-record-join-show-up-in-main-section/28221145#comment44805400_28219751)

Comment: Appreciate it guys!  I will give it a shot.  Thanks for helping out a newbie.

Comment: I am actually getting this, looks like it is not returning the primary location zipcode.  Any help is appreciated!:
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
-<source>
-<job>
<job_id>15000005</job_id>
-<location_zipcode>
<![CDATA[77002]]>
<![CDATA[77050]]>
<![CDATA[]]>
</location_zipcode>
</job>
</source>

Comment: Nevermind, figured out what the issue was there.  Thanks Again! G

Comment: This worked with one record but now with multiple records this xsl is placing all the zipcodes on the output for each and every job_id
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<source>
   <job>
      <job_id>15000005</job_id>
      <location_zipcode>
<![CDATA[77002]]>
<![CDATA[77050]]>
<![CDATA[77003]]>
<![CDATA[77005]]>
<![CDATA[77051]]>
<![CDATA[77006]]>
</location_zipcode>
   </job>
   <job>
      <job_id>15000006</job_id>
      <location_zipcode>
<![CDATA[77002]]>
<![CDATA[77050]]>
<![CDATA[77003]]>
<![CDATA[77005]]>
<![CDATA[77051]]>
<![CDATA[77006]]>
</location_zipcode>
   </job>
</source>

Comment: Please don't post code in comments, it's unreadable. If you have a follow-up question involving a different scenario, edit your original question and add your new input, along with the expected output. Or post a new question (depending on how different the new scenario is).

Comment: Gotcha.  I actually ended up figuring it out :) Will definitely remember your comment for next time.  Thanks! G